# \def does not work in trim

Tags: floats

I am trying to use a variable `\def\cc{5cm}` to trim but it doesnt compile below. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\cc{5cm}
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \subfloat[]{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,trim={0 \cc 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}   
     \label{steady_state}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `{0 {\cc} 0 0}` should work. Please, remove all unnecessary bits: just the `\includegraphics` suffices to show the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The example can be minimized to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\def\cc{5cm}

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,trim={0 \cc 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that, according to TeX parsing rules, there is *no* space after `\cc`.

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cc}{5cm}

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,trim={0 {\cc} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Don't carelessly use `\def`: you risk to redefine important commands. Try with `\def\box{5cm}` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: LaTeX will collapse after `\def\box{5cm}` but OpTeX will not. -:)

Comment: @wipet LaTeX was born when computers had heavy memory limitations.

Comment: @egreg: (So) LaTeX will be expire in future?

Comment: It doesn't seem that today's LaTeX saves memory. If I do simple test `ls -lah lualatex.fmt` and  `ls -lah optex.fmt` I get the following result: lualatex: 4,4M, optex: 679K. (Note that OpTeX knows colors, hyperlinks, bib, smart verbatim, graphic etc. but LaTeX kernel doesn't know these.) So, the argument about saving memory is not true today. Especially not for LaTeX.

Comment: @wipet You're comparing apples and oranges. When LaTeX was born (about 40 years ago) it was simply out of the question to redefine all primitives. Since LaTeX aims to be an archival format, it's not possible to change the setup now, or millions of documents might break.

Comment: This is not answer to the question why today's LaTeX is so memory eater if we want only to keep it as archival format.